# Static counter in Ruby inside multithreaded environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, puma

```
class MyCounter
  @counter = 0

  def self.get_count
    @counter
  end

  def self.track!
    @counter+=1

    store_to_database_and_restart_counter! if @counter == 1000
  end

  def self.store_to_database_and_restart_counter!
    # store to database ... 
    @counter = 0
  end
end
```

I want to use counter like above in Rails app which runs via Puma with multiple workers & threads. Because RPS will be super high I don't want to use Redis.

I am wondering about thread safety. What should I be careful about?

Each worker will have it's own copy of `@counter` right?
Hwever for threads, they will share same `@counter`? I wonder whether it is possible that 2 threads would call `store_to_database_and_restart_counter!` simulateneously? I think it is not possible but I would like to make sure that this is true :)

Comment: _"I would like to make sure that this is true"_ – use a mutex to limit access to one thread.

Comment: If you want thread safety and atomicity, what exactly is wrong with Redis and INCR? I would think 130k requests/sec from Redis should be high enough performance, right?

Comment: @anothermh - Redis is taking 30% of the average request time. It is fast but it could be faster if I would use internal data structure (internal vs external memory).  I am considering option to increase conter in Redis every second request (or e.g. every 1000th request)

Comment: Is your Redis instance not running on the same server as Rails? I can only imagine Redis taking that long for a network request.

Comment: @Stefan do you know .. Should something as simple as `@counter+=1` wrapped inside a semaphore?

Comment: @anothermh yes - Redis is shared. Each request is taking only few ms but time is being compounded .. :)

Comment: @knagode you probably want to wrap the entire method body in a semaphore, not just the first line.